# Selenium capture briefly appearing loading gif

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-testing

How do I verify if the loading gif appears upon a div load? I see that the gif appears on screen when the content is being reloaded. But the reload is too quick and the gif disappears before selenium can find it. Is there way to trigger from js back to selenium that the gif appeared? (that can work consistently; slow or fast reloads)